# Java как генерировать код, в зависимости от аннотаций

Tags: java, generate

Мне стало интересно, а при помощи чего можно генерировать код в методах, описывая, что генерировать аннотациями?

---

К примеру, есть библиотека Lombok, которая генерирует код, в зависимости от аннотаций. Есть аннотация `@NonNull`, которая применяется вот так:

```
void method(@NonNull Object arg)  {}
```

И она генерирует проверку, что-то вроде:

```
if (arg == null) 
    throw new NullPointerException();
```

Но, порывшись в исходниках библиотеки, я понял, что ничего не понял.

---

Собственно вопрос: а как это так можно генерировать код, беря любые поля класса/метода на стадии компиляции?

Comment: Для этого предусмотрены Annotation processor-ы, которые могут быть указаны во время компиляции и они вызываются компилятором как только он увидит аннотацию, соответствующую данному процессору. Ну и процессор наверное может что-то там нагенерировать. С этим делом я уже не знаком. Погуглите по ключевым словам java code generation annotation processor compile time

Comment: А подключаются процессоры очень просто. Так же как любой jar-ник просто перечисляются в classpath. Внутри META-INF есть специальный файл, по которому компилятор понимает, что это не какая-то вшивая библиотека, а процессор аннотаций.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Lombok` основан на [`annotation processing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html). Для генерации кода используется `cglib`. Но сам [jsr 269](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269) не предполагает изменение байткода компилируемых классов. Он предоставляет механизм только для создания новых классов, анализа существующих и пр. Поэтому `lombok` опирается на 
внутренние классы компилятора, совместимость которых между версиями не гаратируется, отчасти там такой, несколько запутанный, код.